# C++ class Shape has no member named set_values

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

Classes Triangle, Rectangle inherits shape. I want to make an array that holds elements of Shape type, either Triangle or Rectangle. I write:

```
Shape** foo = new Shape*[2];
foo[0] = new Triangle();
foo[0].set_values(3,5) // set_values function exist only in Triangle class
```

and this gives me `class Shape has no member named set_values`. How can I call the set_values function?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't tell. Chances are it's `foo[0]->set_values` instead though.

Comment: You need to cast foo[0] into the Triangle class. You can do this by using dynamic_cast like this: Triangle* triangle = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(foo[0]). You can then call set_values as follows triangle->set_values(3,5). Avoid static_cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape** foo = new Shape*[2];
foo[0] = new Triangle();
// foo[0].set_values(3,5) // set_values function exist only in Triangle class
Triangle* tri = static_cast<Triangle*>(foo[0]);
tri->set_values(3,5);
```